# What is the role of command track officers in Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Everyone is familiar with the gold shirts of TOS and the red shirts of DS9/TNG, the ‘command track’ officers, but I’m somewhat confused about how their responsibilities contrast with ‘operations’, ‘engineering’, security, etc.

Were there roles that command track officers could occupy that other tracks could not? Obviously, all the main captains of the various shows have been in command colors, but is that coincidence, part of a captain’s uniform, or something else? Were there bridge positions that could not be occupied by a command track officer?

Comment: I always just assumed "command track" was something analogous to [commissioned officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officer_(armed_forces)), whereas "operations", etc, would be NCOs or warrant officers.  No particular sources, though, just my assumption.

Comment: Nah, Trek has explicitly noncoms: Miles O’Brien, for instance.

Comment: They tell everyone else what to do.